# SQL for getting sum of a column

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have three tables linked each other.

```
mysql> select * from tablea;
+----+--------+
| id | name   |
+----+--------+
|  1 | Item 1 |
|  2 | Item 2 |
+----+--------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from tableb;
+----+------+----------+
| id | Aid  | name     |
+----+------+----------+
|  1 |    1 | B Item 1 |
|  2 |    2 | B Item 2 |
|  3 |    1 | B Item 3 |
+----+------+----------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from tablec;
+----+------+----------+-------+
| id | Bid  | name     | value |
+----+------+----------+-------+
|  1 |    1 | C Item 1 |    10 |
|  2 |    2 | C Item 2 |    20 |
|  3 |    1 | C Item 3 |    15 |
|  4 |    2 | C Item 4 |     5 |
|  5 |    3 | C Item 5 |    12 |
+----+------+----------+-------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

TableA is linked to TableB with Aid, TableC is linked with TableB with Bid.

What I want is the id of tableA and the sum of values of all the TableC items comes under it.

The result set I expect for the above example is

```
+-----------+--------+
| tablea.id | sum    |
+-----------+--------+
|         1 |     37 |
|         2 |     25 |
+-----------+--------+
```

Comment: Have you tried joining them?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
SELECT  a.ID, SUM(c.value) totalValue
FROM    tablea a
        INNER JOIN tableb b
            On a.ID = b.AID
        INNER JOIN tablec c
            ON b.ID = c.BID
GROUP BY a.ID
```

if there's a possibility that `ID` from tableA doesn't exist on other tables and you also want to show their result, use `LEFT JOIN` instead

```
SELECT  a.ID, COALESCE(SUM(c.value), 0) totalValue
FROM    tablea a
        LEFT JOIN tableb b
            On a.ID = b.AID
        LEFT JOIN tablec c
            ON b.ID = c.BID
GROUP BY a.ID
```

- [**SQLFiddle Demo for both queries**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/44ae1/1)

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT a.id, SUM(c.value) sum
FROM TableA a
INNER JOIN TableB b ON a.id = b.AID
INNER JOIN TableC c ON b.id = c.BID
GROUP BY a.id
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b526a/1)

Answer (score 3):

You can try this query

```
SELECT a.id AS A, SUM(c.value) AS SUM FROM tablea a INNER JOIN tableb b ON a.id = b.Aid INNER JOIN tablec c ON b.id = c.Bid GROUP BY a.id;
```